# Java import wildcard not importing everything inside package

Tags: java, import, awt, actionlistener, wildcard

I'm writing a Java program that has a button with an action listener:

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Change");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(textField.getText());
        }
    });
```

At the top of the file, I have these two import statements:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

I know this is terrible practice, I am revising for an exam and it's way easier and quicker to just write that at the top of the page.

I get an error, however, telling me to import `java.awt.event.ActionListener`

If the `event` package is inside `java.awt` and I used the wildcard `*` to import everything, then why is it not being imported??

Comment: Because it's not recursive; `x.y.z` is **not** a sub-package of `x.y` in any useful sense.

Comment: [Apparent Hierarchies of Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the definition of type-import-on-demand in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2):

> A type-import-on-demand declaration allows all accessible types of a
>   named package or type to be imported as needed.
>
> TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration: `import` PackageOrTypeName . * ;

It is important to understand the terminology: "all accessible types of a named package" means all the types whose `package` declaration is *specifically* the one before the `.*`.

So, if a class's package is defined like:

```
package my.pkg.name;
```

Then it will be available to `import my.pkg.name.*`, but if a class is defined like:

```
package my.pkg.name.subname;
```

Then it will not be available to `import my.pkg.name.*`, because it does not belong to that package. It specifically belongs to `my.pkg.name.subname` which is - as far as Java is concerned - a different package.

It is true that Java implementations normally expect the packages to be ordered in a directory hierarchy, so the directory for `my.pkg.name.subname` is going to be under the directory of `my.pkg.name`. If you think of it, supposed you wrote

```
ls my/pkg/name/*
```

In that directory. It behaves very much the same: it would give you only the files under this directory directly, not the directories further under it. The semantics of type-import-on-demand is pretty much the same (excluding the `subname` "directory" itself, because it is not a type).

Answer (score 2):

`java.awt.*` doesn't include `java.awt.event.ActionListener`. `java.awt.event` is not a sub package of `java.awt`. `import java.awt.event.*` would include `java.awt.event.ActionListener`.

Comment: I don't quite understand why `java.awt.event` isn't inside `java.awt`? Surely `java.awt.*` would include `java.awt.event` and `java.*` would include `java.awt`?

Comment: It is just to avoid import of all things in the world by a wildcard, because it could take forever to compile your app if you would be allowd do that.